# Query using BETWEEN on a Text value is exclusive when used with '%'?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Fruits

```
ID    fruit_name  
1     Apple  
2     Banana  
3     Cherry  
4     Watermelon  
5     Cucumber
```

query

```
select * from Fruits where fruit_name between 'A%' and 'C%';
```

Result

```
ID    fruit_name  
1     Apple  
2     Banana
```

My question is why does it not return the result below since between is inclusive

Result

ID fruit_name
1 Apple
2 Banana
3 Cherry
5 Cucumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a range comparison here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruits
WHERE fruit_name > 'A' and fruit_name < 'D';
```

This would return all fruits which are lexicographically larger than `A` but before `D`, implying that all fruits starting with A, B, or C would be included.

A regex option would also work here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruits
WHERE fruit_name REGEXP '^[A-C]';
```

Comment: You _can't_ use the `%` wildcard operators with `WHERE`, they are only valid for `LIKE`.

Comment: Yes, I get that the above solutions work but why does the original query not return the intended result, while ` select * from Fruits where fruit_name between 'A%' and 'D%';` gives the intended result.

Comment: When you say `BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'C%'`, you are actually saying all fruits which fall in between the text `A%` and `C%`.  Most likely, the `%` character is earlier than the letters, hence no fruit starting with `C` is matching.